# Bootstrap nav-tabs check for selected tab using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Bootstrap nav tabs:

```
 <div class="row spiff_tabs_body">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs spiff_tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Potential Spiff</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/instantspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Instant Spiff</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="delayedspiff"></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="instantspiff"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to check which tab is selected and then display an alert.  I have the following javascript in my view:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff');        
});
</script>

<script>
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // here is the new selected tab id
    var selectedTabId = e.target.id;
    var id = $('.tab-content .active').attr('id');
    if (id == "delayedspiff") {
        alert("delayedspiff");
    } else {
        alert("instantspiff");
    }
});   
</script>
```

When I click the tabs it works, but the alert always displays delayedspiff.  I need to dislay instantspiff when they click on the instantspiff tab.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove class `active` from all tabs and add it to the tab which was clicked.

EDIT: In order to get the id of clicked tab, try using an attribute data-id on the tab selections.

```
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-id="delayedspiff" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Potential Spiff</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" data-id="instantspiff" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/instantspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Instant Spiff</a>
                </li>

<script>
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var wrongid = $('.tab-content .active').attr('id');
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass("active"); // remove class active from all tabs
    $(this).addClass("active"); // add class active to the current tab
    var correctid = $(this).data("id"); // get the attribute data-id of the clicked tab
    alert($('.tab-content .active')[0].outerHTML); // shows why you are getting the incorrect id
    if (correctid == "delayedspiff") 
      alert("delayedspiff");
    else 
      alert("instantspiff");    
});   
</script>
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14313/

Comment: DinoMyte I tried this, I added my conditional statement, but it still always displays delayedspiff inthe alert box no matter which tab I select.  Do I have someone wrong with the if statement?

Comment: Its not going to give you the id of the selected tab because the event has not yet finished clicking the new tab. I've updated the solution. Hopefully this helps you achieving what is needed.

Comment: Wait I got it!  Thanks for your help!